OpenLayers: WFS response (GML2) is highlighted. But not transformed correctly?
Based on the previous stackoverflow issue. I have a map with polygon displayed highlighted in red with the click on the map. New features are rendered as expected and instead they are landing somewhere else. The transformation is not working correctly for the function featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() and this is highlighting polygon in the totally different coordinate system. I've tried also, the function  features.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25832');
without success.
Please steps & code below:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
        <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
           proj4.defs(
    "EPSG:25832",
    "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
  );
  // ensure OL knows about the PROJ4 definitions
  ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

    var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: "EPSG:25832",
      center: ol.proj.transform(
        [7.07748, 51.16497],
        "EPSG:4326",
        "EPSG:25832"
      ),
      zoom: 17,
    }),
  });

  var Gebaeude_Photovoltaik_2023 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    opacity: 0.7,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      params: { LAYERS: "photovoltaik_gebaeudesummen" },
      url: "https://gdi-ows2.solingen.de/ows/SG_SOLAR",
      projection: "EPSG:25832",
    }),
  });

  map.addLayer(Gebaeude_Photovoltaik_2023);

  const source = new ol.source.Vector();

  map.addLayer(
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "red",
          width: 5,
        }),
      }),
    })
  );


           map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;

    var tol = 1;
    var bbox1 = [evt.coordinate[0] - tol, evt.coordinate[1] - tol];
    var bbox2 = [
      evt.coordinate[0] + parseInt(tol),
      evt.coordinate[1] + parseInt(tol),
    ];
    var bbox_1 = ol.proj.toLonLat(bbox1, "EPSG:25832", "EPSG:4326");
    var bbox_2 = ol.proj.toLonLat(bbox2, "EPSG:25832", "EPSG:4326");
    var bbox = [bbox_1, bbox_2];
    

    var url =
      "https://gdi-ows2.solingen.de/ows/SG_SOLAR?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&format=GML2&typename=photovoltaik_gebaeudesummen" +
      "&srsName=EPSG:4326&bbox=" +
      bbox;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((text) => {
        // console.log(text);
        const features = new ol.format.WFS().readFeatures(text, {
          dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
          featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        });
        source.clear();
        // console.log(map.getView().getProjection());
        // console.log(features);
        // var src = 'EPSG:4326';
        // var dest = 'EPSG:25832';
        // features.ol.getGeometry().transform(src, dest);

        source.addFeatures(features);

        map.getView().setCenter(source.getExtent());
      });
  });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



Problem:  is there method (best strategy), that the features are always transformed and highlighted on the map where we have clicked in 'EPSG:25832' coordinate system.
An example would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It is not GML2 format but it does return EPSG:4326 with GML2 axis order.  As the service directly supports EPSG:25832 you could use that as the SRS without any transforms being needed.  Otherwise you could use EPSG:3857 and transform to/from that.

Example using EPSG:25832 for WFS


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
        <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
           proj4.defs(
    "EPSG:25832",
    "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
  );
  // ensure OL knows about the PROJ4 definitions
  ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

    var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: "EPSG:25832",
      center: ol.proj.transform(
        [7.07748, 51.16497],
        "EPSG:4326",
        "EPSG:25832"
      ),
      zoom: 17,
    }),
  });

  var Gebaeude_Photovoltaik_2023 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    opacity: 0.7,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      params: { LAYERS: "photovoltaik_gebaeudesummen" },
      url: "https://gdi-ows2.solingen.de/ows/SG_SOLAR",
      projection: "EPSG:25832",
    }),
  });

  map.addLayer(Gebaeude_Photovoltaik_2023);

  const source = new ol.source.Vector();

  map.addLayer(
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "red",
          width: 5,
        }),
      }),
    })
  );


           map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
    const coordinate = evt.coordinate;

    var tol = 1;
    var bbox1 = [evt.coordinate[0] - tol, evt.coordinate[1] - tol];
    var bbox2 = [
      evt.coordinate[0] + parseInt(tol),
      evt.coordinate[1] + parseInt(tol),
    ];
    var bbox = [bbox1, bbox2];
    

    var url =
      "https://gdi-ows2.solingen.de/ows/SG_SOLAR?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&format=GML2&typename=photovoltaik_gebaeudesummen" +
      "&srsName=EPSG:25832&bbox=" +
      bbox;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((text) => {
        // console.log(text);
        const features = new ol.format.WFS().readFeatures(text);
        source.clear();
        // console.log(map.getView().getProjection());
        // console.log(features);
        // var src = 'EPSG:4326';
        // var dest = 'EPSG:25832';
        // features.ol.getGeometry().transform(src, dest);

        source.addFeatures(features);

        map.getView().setCenter(source.getExtent());
      });
  });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



